# Straightening a face image within Canvas using click-points

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to build a small app where my users can straighten up a tilted face with just **2 clicks**

I ask my users to click on the **middle of the nose** and the **middle of the eyebrows** of the face within the image.

From there I get 2 points `eyebrowMiddle(x1,y1)` and `noseMiddle (x2,y2).`

> Is it possible via these 2 points to calculate how much Canvas
>   rotation I need to have to rotate the image and make the face straight
>   in relation to the canvas rectangle?
>
> Also, how can I detect and adjust accordingly if the image is tilted
>   to the left or right?

Here is a more descriptive image to show you what I mean now.

[image: Tilted face with user click points and an imaginary line]

---

**PS:**

- `x1,y1` and `x2,y2` are in relation to the canvas perimeter of
  course, not the browser window or anything else.
- We have tried the line equation such as m = (x2-x1) / (y2-y1) but the
  result is always near 1 so I don't think we are following the right
  course at the moment.
- We don't care if the image looks wrong in the canvas as long as the
  face features are parallel in relation to the bottom of the canvas
  (they should be looking straight).

Comment: Just giving an update for you guys, the line equation is correct although it is in arctans and it needs to be converted to degrees before it's usable as a canvas rotation value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform such a rotation, you need to decide of the pivot point. Here i choose the eyebrow.
Then you have to choose a point in the target canvas where this pivot point will be hooked. I decided to choose the point at middle x coordinates, and at fourth of the screen in y.
To compute the rotation angle, you have to use atan2, which will nicely give you the angle for a given deltaY / deltaX in between two points ( angle = Math.atan2 (  delta y , delta x ) ) .

Then to draw :
- Translate to the target point.
- rotate by right angle.
- draw the image centering on its pivot.

ET VOILA, it works :-)

```
function rotate() {
  ctx.save();
  // go to default center position
  ctx.translate(eyeBrowTargetPosition.x, eyeBrowTargetPosition.y);
  // compute angle 
  var yDelta = noseMiddle.y - eyebrowMiddle.y;
  var xDelta =  noseMiddle.x - eyebrowMiddle.x ;
  var angle = Math.atan2 (yDelta ,xDelta);
  // compensate for angle
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  //draw image centering input on eyebrow
  ctx.drawImage(face, -eyebrowMiddle.x, -eyebrowMiddle.y);
  ctx.restore();
};
```

jsbin is here :
http://jsbin.com/wavokaku/2/edit?js,output

result with an approximation of the existing green dots :

[image]

Comment: First of all thanks! The answer is really descriptive and all. I tried the solution with the Arctan = (x2-x1) / (y2-y1) and I got a result anyway. But the user only approximates a solution since he cannot hit the points that are needed to ''perfectly straighten'' the image. Touch devices perform even worse since the click positions are really not quite accurate themselves. I've resorted to manual rotation by the user via buttons which perform relatively far better than the solution I requested here. Thank you very much anyway tho but the image needs to be really straight in my case

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides you're welcome ! Prefer atan2, which avoid the division by 0 issue + sign issues. In fact i have the algorithm in my head to perform automatic centering, but it's quite some work to build it.

Comment: Wait,you mean perfectly straight?

Comment: I mean nicely straight for a face that is facing the screen. I guess it's one day of work to have it work.

Comment: What is the logic behind it? I would reckon it has something to do with eyebrow detection if I didn't go too far

Comment: MMM room is short here. Basic idea : build a function that returns the 'mirrorness' of a part of an image. It would add the abs of the point's hue on the right and on the left part of an image. We have to use rgb->hsl conversion since delta of r,g,b wouldn't mean much. We would check mirrorness of only an area near the two provided points. Then, the algo. would check the mirorness of various images with shifted start/end points and keep best points.